Science fiction anthology book with stories about a biologist studying an alien worm and an SOS from an offline space station
In middle school, About 16 years ago I read a soft paper back anthology with two stories I remember in great detail.
The first was about a biologist studying a miraculous worm from some alien world that had at least ten different sexes and their mating habits for the reproduction cycle.
The second story included a security detail looking for a high priority individual whose SOS went off in an offline space station.
Inside was a massive medical experimentation facility that had been corrupted and sentient. With one room full of sheets of skin of varying shade's. Roamed by cultivator Autons that would Shred them to piece with the Mantid like blades used to harvest the skin for grafting.
I can't find it anywhere and I'd be very greatful for any insights to titles.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to remember any details of the cover art?

For the record, paramecium(s) have ten sexes. No scifi required :-)

Were the terms "autons" and "mantid-like blades" actually found in the story?

Were the worms intelligent? What was "miraculous" about them? Could they work healing miracles, or what? Was the biologist a man or a woman? Was he or she studying them on their native planet?

Was the "high priority individual" a wanted criminal, or an important dignitary that the security detail was supposed to protect? What is a "cultivator" "Auton"?

In Glacial by Alastair Reynolds a missing scientist was studying worms with at least three sexes on an ice world. The scientist believed the worms could form an emergent intelligence. Could this be the story you're thinking of?
